# Xamarin forms, iOS custom renderer font size

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using code below to set custom font to all of my buttons, all buttons have my new font and everything is good, the problem is **`font size`**, when I change it in xaml, nothing changes.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using LAVA.iOS.CustomRenderer;
using LAVA.Utils.CustomRenderer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]

namespace LAVA.iOS.CustomRenderer
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{ 
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;
        Control.Layer.BorderColor = e.NewElement.BorderColor.ToCGColor();
        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = (nfloat) e.NewElement.BorderWidth;
        Control.Layer.CornerRadius = e.NewElement.BorderRadius;
        try
        {
            Control.Font = AppDelegate.GetFont(Control.Font.PointSize);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
  }
```

}

this is my `AppDelegate.GetFont()` method:

```
public static UIFont GetFont(nfloat fontSize)
    {
        if (AppFont == null)
            AppFont = UIFont.FromName(Constants.FONT_IOS, fontSize);
        else if (AppFont.PointSize != fontSize)
            AppFont.WithSize(fontSize);
        return AppFont;
    }
```

but the font size does not change.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.. But it looks like you just get the same font size returned from `GetFont`?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, No! I get `Control` font size and pass it to `GetFont` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a property on e.NewElement (e.g. e.NewElement.FontSize) to get the desired font size. Control is the native control, so you're just getting a font with the same size that was already there.